# Ubuntu 10.04 upgrade: gdm-simple-greeter no seat-id found

Tags: login, ubuntu-10.04, gdm

Upgraded a machine straight from Ubuntu 8.04 to 10.04. After a successful upgrade, GDM shows no users on the login screen, with the error message: "gdm-simple-greeter no seat-id found"

Users can log in via text mode. A recovery user can startx without issue. I'm convinced this is an issue with GDM and/or ConsoleKit.

What are my options? I've debated a reinstall but would rather not. I've also thought of switching to KDM or XDM instead.

I've filed a launchpad bug--no responses yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to KDM works. I don't think the Ubuntu community have even *triaged* this bug yet.